# Does jQuery .fail() method accept a callback as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does the jQuery `.fail()` method accept a callback as a parameter? For example:

```
$.get( "test.txt" )
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "$.get failed!" );
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried it? what was happening then?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [fail](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) method documentation

Comment: The example looks pretty similar to mine. So it does work, thanks!

Comment: Is your queston "Will it accept a callback function in a general sense" or "Can that function be anonymous?" In JS you can use an anonymous function expression anywhere that a function reference is expected.

Comment: I'm asking if it is possible for a callback anonymous function to be a parameter.

Comment: @MichaelBao A function object is a function object is a value. It does not matter if it is the result of a function expression (an "anonymous function") or the result of evaluating an identifier that corresponds to a function name. In both cases the expression is evaluated; and the result of the evaluation (which is a value, possibly a function object) is supplied as an argument. Otherwise: RTFineM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It actually takes *one or more* callback functions.

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/):

> deferred.fail( failCallbacks [, failCallbacks ] )
>   **failCallbacks**
>   Type: Function()
>   A function, or array of functions, that are called when the Deferred is rejected.
>   **failCallbacks**
>   Type: Function()
>   Optional additional functions, or arrays of functions, that are called when the Deferred is rejected.

The method signature in the documentation appears to be slightly wrong, however. It should probably be something like this:

> deferred.fail( failCallback [, ...failCallbacks ] )

It could even be made simpler than that:

> deferred.fail( ...failCallbacks )

Comment: From the very docs you linked: "*The deferred.fail() method accepts one or more arguments*". Not two. Admittedly, the signature should've been `.fail(failCallback[, ...failCallbacks])`